Why is useLayoutEffect used in useClickAway React Hook?
Here's the source for useClickAway hook:
export function useClickAway(cb) {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const refCb = React.useRef(cb);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    refCb.current = cb;
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (e) => {
      const element = ref.current;
      if (element && !element.contains(e.target)) {
        refCb.current(e);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handler);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", handler);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handler);
      document.removeEventListener("touchstart", handler);
    };
  }, []);

  return ref;
}

I am particularly interested in the usage of useLayoutEffect here. The documentation of useLayoutEffect suggests it should only ever be used when working with layout and I don't see anything of that sort happening.
Why not just use the following which updates the callback ref to the latest cb whenever it changes?
React.useEffect(() => {
  refCb.current = cb;
}, [cb]);

My assumption is useLayoutEffect synchronously runs before the browser repaints so updating refCb there means a much more guaranteed and correct callback on the immediate click after browser repaint whereas a useEffect would probably be slower being asynchronous and within that slowness, a click could still execute the previous callback.
Is my understanding correct or is there a deeper reason for why useLayoutEffect is being used here?

It seems like useLayoutEffect() call was added to remove the cb's stale closure. A common practice to fix the stale-closure issue is to use useLayoutEffect as it's "safer" in the more general sense, and I'm guessing the code author did it that way due to that. There are other scenarios where using a useLayoutEffect would have observable differences, but since the ref is self-contained with the custom hook, I don't see it being an issue if it were a useEffect

It is potentially worth leaving a comment on that PR to get more insights from the author if you don't get anything here.

@NickParsons thanks for the link. It does seem like the stale closure problem is solved by updating the ref and the earliest way to do that is in useLayoutEffect while useEffect runs later. I'll try to post a comment on that PR later. React docs should include this usage of useLayoutEffect in its API reference.
